# HighCharts - Selection Event keep the selection marked in graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Does anyone know how to keep the selection in a graph in HighCharts?

```
$(function () {
    var $report = $('#report');

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                selection: function(event) {
                    if (event.xAxis) {
                        $report.html('min: '+ event.xAxis[0].min +', max: '+ event.xAxis[0].max);
                    } else {
                        $report.html ('Selection reset');
                    }
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse()
        }]
    });
});
```

Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection/

Let's say once I select an area of the graph, the area remains selected until the user makes a new selection or resets the zoom. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) from Highcharts site - bottom chart called master is using `addPlotBand()` to mark (un)selected area.